# strcmp inside if does not work inside function

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am writing a function which receives several arrays as arguments, as follows:

```cpp
const int numofparticles = 20;
const int numofdims = 46;
const int numforn = 222;
const int forn_sem_repet = 92;

float cost(float x[numofdims], float M[numofdims][numforn], char prod[numofdims][102], char forn_list[numforn][102], float qtde[numofdims][1], float min_prices[forn_sem_repet], char min_forn[forn_sem_repet][102]){
    float v = 0;
    vector<string> forn;
    vector<float> total;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<numofdims;i++){
        if(x[i] != -1){
            forn.push_back(forn_list[(int)x[i]]);
            total.push_back(qtde[i][1] * M[i][(int)x[i]]);
            for(j=i+1;j<numofdims;j++){
                if(strcmp(forn_list[(int)x[j]],forn.back()) == 0){
                    total.back() += qtde[j][1] * M[j][(int)x[j]];
                    x[j] = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<numofdims;i++){
        v += qtde[i][1] * M[i][(int)x[i]];
    }
    int lin;
    for(i=0;i<forn.size();i++){
        for(int ii=0;ii<forn_sem_repet;ii++){
            if(strcmp(forn[i],min_forn[lin]) == 0){
                lin = ii;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(total[i] < min_prices[lin]){
            v += 1000;
        }
    }

    return v;
 }
```

And it returns an error in both `strcmp()`.

```
error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’
                 if(strcmp(forn_list[(int)x[j]],forn.back()) == 0){
```

and

```
error: cannot convert ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int strcmp(const char*, const char*)’
             if(strcmp(forn[i],min_forn[lin]) == 0){
```

However, in the `main` function, after loading all the variables, the loop.

```cpp
for(i=0;i<numforn;i++){
            for(j=0;j<forn_sem_repet;j++){
                if(strcmp(forn_list[i],min_forn[j]) == 0){
                    printf("%s\n%s  %d  %d", forn_list[i],min_forn[j],i,j);
                    printf("\n\n");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Works exactly as expected.

What can be done to solve this problem in the function `cost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function, you've declared `vector<string> forn;`, and that is incompatible with the line `if(strcmp(forn_list[(int)x[j]],forn.back()) == 0){`, since `strcmp` can only take C-style `char*` strings as argument, not `std::string`. That is exactly what the compiler is complaining about.

To make your code work, replace `forn.back()` in that line with `forn.back().c_str()`.

Comment: I believe the correct replacement would be `forn.back().c_str()`